# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when using Onehotencoder on multiple columns

Tags: machine-learning

I'm fairly new to machine learning and I am using the following code to encode my categorical data for preprocessing:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'), [0])],remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

which works when I only have one categorical column of data in X. 
However when I have multiple columns of categorical data I change my code to :

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'), [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,14,15])],remainder='passthrough')
```

but I get the following error when calling the np.array function:

**Value Error: setting an array element with a sequence**

on the np.array function call...

From what I understand all I need to do is specify which columns I'm hot encoding as in the above line of code...so why does one work and the other give an error?  What should I do to fix it?

**Also:** if I remove the
`dtype=np.float`
from the np.array function I don't get an error - but I also don't get anything returned in X

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I was able to answer my own question.

For anyone interested what I did was change the line

```
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

to:

```
X = ct.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

The code works perfectly now.